# Why aren't my assets being moved when building an electron app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I have begun developing an app using Electron, GitHub's desktop application framework.  I am using the [Electron Boilerplate](https://github.com/szwacz/electron-boilerplate).

To run the app I run `npm install` followed by `npm start`.  This works great with the initial boilerplate.

I now want to integrate jQuery.  To do this I add:

```
<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./assets/scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js');
</script>
```

Unfortunately this spits out an error in the dev console stating it can't be found.  I'm assuming it's all running from the `/build` directory, where the assets aren't.

So my questions:

1. Should the assets from my assets folder (`/assets/js` and `/assets/css`) be copied upon `npm start`/`npm install`?
2. Is the app running from `/build` or is there another problem here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!  I had to amend the `build.js` within `/tasks/build/` to include my newly created assets directory.

Comment: Glad you figured it out :)